# How do I turn on CSS Overview when it is not an option within development tools

Tags: css

I got a message that says:

```
"To use xxx , the CSS on your browser must be enabled"
```

I followed the instructions online that read:

> 1. Open up DevTools ( Command + Option + I on Mac; Control + Shift + I on
>    Windows)
> 2. Head over to DevTool Settings ( ? or Function + F1 on Mac; ?
>    or F1 on Windows)
> 3. Click open the Experiments section.
> 4. Enable the CSS
>    Overview option.

but when I go to the development tools there is not an option to choose css overview.

Development tools has no "enable CSS Overview" option.

Comment: Which browser, what platform?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're following instructions for Chrome users... so I'm responding with an answer based on Chrome.

> CSS Overview is no longer in Experiments.
> It’s now available in the “More tools” submenu under the “⋮” menu.**

[image]

Comment: I do not see this option anymore, do you know if it's still in use and where we can find it or did they removed it ?

Comment: @HDJEMAI I really don't know how to respond to that. I've just looked it up again and it's still there for me. [See link here](https://imgur.com/r8XJ6iX)